# How to create url inside $state in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to create an URL like:

`http://localhost:3000/home/#/student/studentId=63`

or

`http://localhost:3000/home/#/student:studentId=63`

without using the '?' character.

But the following code is not creating an URL like the ones above:

```
.state('home.student', {
        url: 'student?courseId&studentId',
        controller: 'StudentController',
        templateUrl: 'student.view.html',
      })
```

This state creates an URL like:

`http://localhost:3000/home/#/student?studentId=63`

```
.state('home.student', {
        url: 'student/:courseId/:studentId/',
        controller: 'StudentController',
        templateUrl: 'student.view.html',
      })
```

This state create url like
`http://localhost:3000/home/#/student/63`

Could someone please tell me how to create an URL like:

`http://localhost:3000/home/#/student/studentId=63`

or

`http://localhost:3000/home/#/student:studentId=63`

In the above URLs the '?' character is not needed.

Comment: Why would you want to create non-standard URLs like that? You'll probably have to do alot of extra work. BTW, you are talking about *ui-router*, right?

Comment: [I think your answer is write there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181532/why-give-an-abstract-true-state-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

For url like http://localhost:3000/home/#/student/studentId=63

you coul try:

```
.state('home.student', {
        url: 'student/?studentId',
        controller: 'StudentController',
        templateUrl: 'student.view.html',
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `url` is like a pattern, so just write the pattern you want. For `[your base url for the 'home' state]/student/studentId=63` :

```
$stateProvider.state('home.student', {
  url: '/student/studentId=:studentId',
  controller: 'StudentController',
  templateUrl: 'student.view.html',
})
```