# Angular ui-router nested states - can't specify the parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have the following states declaration (angular v1.5.5):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('appPublic', {
        abstract: true,
        data: { restricted : false }
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        parent: 'appPublic',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    });
```

When I open my site, I don't see the main html content (the `home` state). But, when I remove the `parent: 'appPublic'` declaration - it works then. So, why I can't to specify the state's parent ?

Comment: That's weird, what happens if you remove `abstract : true`?

Comment: well, nothing changes

Answer (score 3):

Every parent, must provide a view target for its child *(if using unnamed views are used, i.e parent is not skipped with absolute view naming - [Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310))*. So this should work

```
.state('appPublic', {
     abstract: true,
     data: { restricted : false },
     template: '<div ui-view=""></div'
 })
```

now, child view (unnamed view) will be placed in the `ui-view` target, declared in parent's template

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/userLogin',
                            {
                                templateUrl: 'WebrtcLogin.html',
                                controller: 'UserLoginController'
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I needed to include `template: '<ui-view/>'` in my abstract state. The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181762/106616